# Multiple close reasons eliminate audits

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

I have been through quite a few audits while reviewing the Close Votes. I have never seen an audit which would have 2 close reasons listed

[image: close reasons]

which automatically means it is never an audit when close reasons > 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're paying close enough attention to notice this, then you've already passed the review audit.

I mean, come on. *You read the boilerplate caption text.* No one does this; they already know what it says. I don't even do it, and I consider myself an extremely conscientious reviewer.

Comment: This is basically what I was about to type. These are designed specifically to catch people that aren't paying any attention to what they're doing. We're not going to make them any more complicated than is necessary for them to serve that purpose, being obvious to those that _are_ awake isn't a problem.

Comment: the *boiler plate caption text* tells you **why** you are reviewing the question. It makes it easier if you are not a robo-reviewer to recognize the reason why somebody wants to close a question. It changes **how** you are *reading* that question and possibly have an impact on your decision.

Comment: @mehow Perhaps. That is a perfectly valid way to use the queue. I do things a bit differently. I read the question with a critical—but unbiased—eye, deciding on my own if it should be closed for any of the existing reasons. Only then will I check my conclusion against the suggestions made by others. And since there are so many not-really-off-topic-reasons crammed into the "off-topic" reason, I'll usually need to open the dialog to get more details.

Comment: @CodyGray but you cannot open the dialog for more details (*other close reasons*) when reviewing an audit. At least that's what I thought happens. And it's mainly the reason I failed 2 or 3 audits. I wanted to click the `Close` as see what other people voted for but it automatically said I have failed even though I haven't chosen the close reason yet. Very frustrating with the *I Understand* thing

Comment: @mehow which is already filed, as a bug IIRC