# Add duplicate tab or remove duplicate test from Close Vote audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Audits which are potentially duplicates have a "Duplicate" tab at the top allowing you to see what it's been marked as a duplicate of:

[image: Working Example]

---

When you get test audits which include *or duplicate*, however, no duplicate tab is displayed. This makes it somewhat obvious that it's a test audit:

[image: Example Duplicate Test Audit]

---

For reference, here is the audit this was from: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3137207 (the question itself isn't actually closed as duplicate anyway!)

Comment: If you notice this you have been paying attention; audit passed :-P

Comment: `"the question itself isn't actually closed as duplicate"` - but (at least) one of the close votes was for duplicate, this can be seen from the "possible duplicate of" comment.

Comment: @Dukeling I was more saying that to show that the question could have been audited as just "unclear what you're asking" and nothing else.

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193482/multiple-close-reasons-eliminate-audits)